# Spring cloud dataflow server connect to REDIS using SSL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

Is there a way to enable ssl connection between Spring cloud dataflow server and REDIS(for analytics). I do not find any configuration option in SCDF documentation. Due to this I always get an error while starting SCDF server. The healthcheck goes down as Redis healthcheck fails.

Comment: Hi, Which version of SCDF server are you using? Since SCDF 2.0, the use of Redis for metrics is replaced by micrometer library.

Comment: I am using 1.7.3 for my batch. Is there a workaround for 1.7.3 release version?